# Скорость загрузки классов Java

Tags: java, classloader

Использую в проекте Spring и Hibernate, разные ServiceDAO, осуществляющие доступ
к данным, имеют уже порядка 30 методов, мне стало интересно, стоит ли их разбивать ради повышения производительности, или кол-во методов в классе не влияет на его скорость загрузки?

Comment: Не думаю, что влияет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не влияет.

На скорость влияет код в методах, а не количество их в классе, т.к. код выполняется многократно, а классы загружаются один раз. Скорость загрузки байт-кода так высока что какие бы то ни было различия будут неощутимы. Выигрыша, даже незначительного, не будет в любом случае т.к. вместо одного класса с 30-ю методами будет загружено три по 10 в каждом.

Более общая мысль: если решили всерьез заняться оптимизацией, то первым делом нужно измерить скорость выполнения кода, найти самые медленные места и сосредоточиться на них. Навряд ли самой медленной частью будет работа загрузчика классов.

Вызовы методов, загрузка классов, JIT-компиляция, как правило, работают быстро. Запрос к БД либо обращение к сервисам займут в тысячи раз больше времени. Запуск сборщика мусора и загрузка сущности из кэша работают в сотни раз медленнее. Экономить на наносекундах можно, но в этом мало смысла когда секунды тратятся впустую.

> стоит ли их разбивать ради повышения производительности

Не стоит. Разбивать классы стоит для организация логики и повышения удобочитаемости.

P.S. [«Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех зол.» Дональд Кнут](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82)

Comment: А если все методы типа getUserByLogin(), getUsersByRating(), getUsersByTags(). По какому принципу их можно разбить, я не совсем понимаю

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил Если честно, сложно дать какой-то дельный совет. Посмотрите где эти методы применяются, возможно можно разделить их относительно бизнес-логики. И да, не факт что класс нужно разбивать.

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил Кстати, можете попробовать подготовить пример кода и опубликовать его с меткой [инспекция-кода]. Возможно, видя код, местные знатоки подскажут какие-нибудь конкретные шаги для улучшения.

Answer (score 1):

"Разбивать классы" следует в соответствии с архитектурными принципами, а не руководствуясь скоростью их загрузки. Если у вас 30 методов в одно классе, то вы явно нарушаете принцип единственной ответственности, как минимум.

Comment: разве принцип единственной ответственности хоть как-то ограничивает количество методов?

Comment: @VladMamaev Роберт Мартин в своём хрестоматийном труде "Чистый код" утверждает, что это один из "запахов" плохого кода и явный признак нарушение этого принципа.